# Swatches configurable display the selection of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an interactive form with the help of javascript. We have a product with multiple select[options], for each color, for memory capacity or for size.

```
var data = [
  {'id': 5, 'in_stock': true, 'color': 2, 'capacity': 2},
  {'id': 2, 'in_stock': true, 'color': 4, 'capacity': 2},
  {'id': 4, 'in_stock': false, 'color': 1, 'capacity': 1}, // disabled option, not have inventary.
  {'id': 10, 'in_stock': true, 'color': 3} // disabled option for all capacity.
]

# to see better please open JSFiddle
```

The idea is that each "id" has some attributes with inventory, *select* act as a filter to the *"array" [data]*, if not stock disabled this option.

[JSFiddle example live.](https://jsfiddle.net/yyy0vnjz/)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You're saying if, for example, the "4 Gigabyte Black" product is unavailable, then the "Add to Cart" button becomes disabled?

Comment: @user2867288 Yes, if you have select 4 Gigabyte Black product is disabled  option.

Comment: This what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/sz7kjfcn/